# Does fluoride anion ever act as a strong field ligand?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

In the case of $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^3+}$ there are $5$ unpaired electrons as water acts as a weak field ligand. But instead of fluoride acting as a weak field ligand in the $\ce{[MnF6]^4-}$ , why does it act as a strong field ligand? In what conditions does it act as a strong field ligand and a weak field ligand?

Comment: Can anybody share their thoughts on this question? Many also consider $\ce{F-}$ to be SFL with $\ce{[NiF6]^2-}$ but not $\ce{[NiF6]^4-}$

Comment: Even with [PtF4]2- behaves as a strong field ligand I think (low spin)

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Whether F- "behaves" as a strong- or weak-field ligand in these complexes has nothing to do with fluoride itself, because fluoride is a constant factor in all of these examples. It's not some magical property of fluoride that's being turned on or off depending on what complex it's in. You should really be asking about the metal and its oxidation state.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes that's why I added another example, wherein both the central metal atom and the ligands are same, the *only* difference being the oxidation state of the metal atom. So my question is rather which "magical property" of the metal/ its oxidation state is being turned "on/off" in such cases?

Comment: May be it related to ligand EN and metal oxidation state?this what CFT tell us.

Comment: @SirArthur7 - $\Delta_o$ always increases with metal oxidation state in complexes with the same metal and same ligands. There are lots of conceptual ways to think about this, but all involve closer interaction between ligand and metal when oxidation state is higher.

Comment: I actually do not see a source actually calling $\ce{MnF6^{4-}$ is low spin.  Is the Emperor actually wearing any clothes?